# Is there a good reason to not Unix-style mangle your From line in an SMTP email header?

Tags: python, email, unix, unicode, smtplib

For context, I've been looking at several examples lately of ways to properly send email potentially containing UTF-8 characters to email addresses also potentially containing UTF-8 characters from Python 2.7 using smtplib.

One thing I came across in a [few](http://www.askthepony.com/blog/2011/06/how-to-send-a-proper-unicode-encoded-email-using-python-2-7/) [examples](https://wordeology.com/computer/how-to-send-good-unicode-email-with-python.html) was people electing to use an `email.Generator` object so that they could override the default `From` header mangling behavior. My understanding is that this mangling behavior (converting the `From` header from "From" to ">From") is in place in order to ensure compatibility with various Unix systems. (I enjoyed reading the [ranting explanations](http://www.softpanorama.org/Mail/index.shtml) of this mangling behavior from the Unix Haters mailing list, for anyone interested in the reasoning behind this behavior).

According to the Python 2.7 docs on [generating MIME documents](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.generator.html#email.generator.Generator), mangling the `From` line in this way...

> [...] is the only guaranteed portable way to avoid having such lines be mistaken for a Unix mailbox format envelope header separator

So, I want to know if there is a good reason to adopt a practice of *not* mangling the `From` header as best practice. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: I can understand such mangling being needed in a data file fomratted in BSD mailbox format contains multiple emails.  The `From` line acts as a separator between emails. But this mangling makes no sense when sending an email over SMTP. There is nothing in the SMTP protocol that warrants or needs this mangling. If an SMTP server receives an email and chooses to store it in an ambiguous format like a BSD mailbox file, it should take care to mangle the received data as it needs.  That is not the responsibility of the email sender to do.